# How to append the data from the JSON

Tags: ios, json

How  to append the data ?

my api as:-

```
[
    {
        "Name": "Vegetables",
        "PictureModel": {
            "ImageUrl": "http://example.jpeg"  
        }
    },
    {
        "Name": "Fruits",
        "PictureModel": {
            "ImageUrl": "http://example1.jpeg"  
        }
     }
]
```

for fetching the data from json

```
 let session = URLSession.shared
        session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            if let response = response {
                print(response)
            }

            if let data = data {
                do {
                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! Array<[String:Any]>
                    print(json)


                    let type = json[0]
                    let name = type["Name"] as! String
                    let PictureModel = type["PictureModel"] as! [String:Any]
                    print(PictureModel)

                    let nameofimage = PictureModel["ImageUrl"]  as! String
                    print(nameofimage)

                    self.fetchedHome.append(Categories(name: name, images: nameofimage))
                    self.tableview.reloadData()


                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }

            }.resume()
```

And i got the output in the tableview .In tableview i got first data as name-vegetable and image in UIImageview.

.But second data not display .So how to append ? how to give for loop and append

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting JSON correctly in print(json)?

If yes, then you should try looping on "json"  as follows :-

```
for (var keyAttr in json) { 
    let dataRow = json[keyAttr]
}
```

Inside the dataRow you can get "Name" and "PictureModel".

I am hoping that it should work.

All the best.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code you will get one by one object in For loop:-

```
if let data = json as? NSArray {
    for data in data {
        if let data = data as? [String: AnyObject] {
            //Here you will get data
            print("Name", data["Name"])
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let session = URLSession.shared
    session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        if let response = response {
            print(response)
        }

        if let data = data {
            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! Array<[String:Any]>
                if let data = json as? [String:Any] {
                    for data in data {

                        let name = data["Name"] as! String
                        let PictureModel = data["PictureModel"] as! [String:Any]
                        print(PictureModel)

                        let nameofimage = PictureModel["ImageUrl"]  as! String
                        print(nameofimage)

                        self.fetchedHome.append(Categories(name: name, images: nameofimage))
                    }
                }
                self.tableview.reloadData()


            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }

        }.resume()
```

Comment: please check i have updted my code in that how to do?

Comment: @brucecraigb have you implement any answer in your code

Comment: i got the answer vegetable but second data is not appended ,so to solve it?\

Comment: here showing an error s :-conditional cast from Array<[String:Any]> to NSArray in the code of:- if let data1 = json as? NSArray {......how to solve it